# Mercurial Lost Work

Tags: mercurial

I committed some changes (call it revision B). Then I did `hg up A` back to an earlier version to fix some bug. Forgetting I had done this update, I realized that I had committed my last changes to the wrong branch. So I `hg rollback` to get rid of that commit (B). It did that part well, but now I am sitting at revision A with the old code, my last commit gone, and `hg st` says everything is up to date at A.

I guess I lost everything that went into commit B? Is there any way to get it back?

Edit: I did not push this anywhere, it all happened locally

Comment: Well, think positive, at least you have learned never to use rollback. The whole point of a VCS is that history changes can't be undone. Unfortunately, DVCS like Mercurial and Git assume that the changes are "yours" in some way, and so allow (even encourage) it. Speaking here as an Hg user.

Comment: @JustOnePixel @Henry Black - misunderstood your question.

Comment: If it makes you feel any better (it won't) there's frequently talk of disabling the rollback command by default, and next time it comes up I'll include a link to your tale of woe.

Comment: Well, you're not getting them back. In the future, it sounds more like a job for rebase or mq to "move" the commit, as it were, instead of destroying and re-committing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your changes are lost - `rollback` completely eliminates the commit ([ref](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FAQ#FAQ.2BAC8-CommonProblems.I_committed_a_change_containing_nuclear_launch_codes.2C_how_do_I_delete_it_permanently.3F))([other ref](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FAQ#FAQ.2BAC8-TechnicalDetails.What_is_the_difference_between_rollback_and_strip.3F)). It's preferable to do`revert` when attempting to access previous changesets, since that doesn't delete any subsquent changesets - it simply changes the current state of your files to look like they did at the changeset you're reverting to.  So if you commit revision B and then revert to revision A, your files will look like they did at revision A, but any changes you make will be put into your next revision C, and revision B will remain in your repo.